# What is the purpose of 1.5 REM bottom margin on Switches in Zurb Foundation?

Tags: css, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-5

Using Foundation 5 and switches: in the SCSS there is a line in the switches section:

```
// $switch-bottom-margin: 1.5rem;
```

Making this `0` rather than `1.5rem` solves a few problems for me. BUT I want to know why Zurb defaulted the `margin-bottom` to `1.5rem`. There are no other examples of this seemingly arbitrary bottom margin assignment that I am aware of.

Comment: In the documentation http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/components/switch.html it suggests that this is to control the switch heights for the default classes and at a guess you would be fine to override this style in your stylesheet